# Is there a way to stop an app creating its own space at the back of the stack when you maximize it?

Tags: spaces

Is there a way to stop an app creating its own space at the back of the stack when you maximize it? I like to have my apps in the same space always but they keep jumping around to the back of the spaces stack, any help appreciated!

I'm using macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

Full-screen windows [always appear in their own spaces](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25574?viewlocale=en_LA&locale=en_LA). This has been the case for a while. There is no way to change it that I am aware of.

The settings that affect which space an app can be in only apply to non-full-screen windows.